# Adding domain names with special character and alternative fails on azure web app

Tags: domain-name, azure-webapps

on an azure webapp i am trying to add custom bindings like this (the names are examples):

træmand.dk

and the common equivalent replacing the æ with ae

traemand.dk

both versions are correctly set up in DNS (not azure) with asuid, and validating both in azure before adding is all good.

BUT i can only add ONE of them. If one is added, then the next one will try, but say "Failed to add hostname træmand.dk. The host name is already assigned to another azure website: (says same website)"

it does not matter which one is added first. The second one will fail.

I have tried using puny codes. But it will not verify the asuid with these.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating a redirection app in a different region that receives one of the versions and redirects to the one chosen to be the official one.

It's a cumbersome workaround, but there seems no way around the "intelligent-same-name"-function. Luckily different regions don't speak with each other, so the alternatives could be configured there.